# Analyzing compositions of complementary CPTP maps with their adjoints

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, operator-theory, matrix-rank

Let us consider two *completely positive* and *trace preserving* (CPTP) linear maps $\Phi:M_d(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_{d_1}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\Phi_c:M_d(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_{d_2}(\mathbb{C})$ that are [*complementary*](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5794/what-is-a-complementary-map) to each other, i.e., there exists an isometry $V:\mathbb{C}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{d_1}\otimes \mathbb{C}^{d_2}$ such that

$$\forall X\in M_d(\mathbb{C}): \quad \Phi(X) = \text{Tr}_2 (VXV^\dagger) \quad\text{and}\quad \Phi_c(X) = \text{Tr}_1 (VXV^\dagger),$$

where $\text{Tr}_1$ and $\text{Tr}_2$ denote partial traces over $M_{d_1}(\mathbb{C})$ and $M_{d_2}(\mathbb{C})$, respectively. We define the [*adjoints*](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12917/what-does-the-adjoint-of-a-channel-represent-physically) $\Phi^*: M_{d_1}(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_{d}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\Phi_c^*:M_{d_2}(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_d(\mathbb{C})$ of these maps uniquely by the following relations: $\forall X\in M_d(\mathbb{C}),\, \forall Y\in M_{d_1}(\mathbb{C}),\, \forall Z\in M_{d_2}(\mathbb{C}):$

$$ \text{Tr}[\Phi(X)Y]=\text{Tr}[X\Phi^*(Y)] \quad\text{and}\quad \text{Tr}[\Phi_c(X)Z]=\text{Tr}[X\Phi_c^*(Z)].$$

It is well-known that the adjoints of CPTP maps are *unital* (i.e., they map the identity matrix to the identity matrix) and completely positive. I am interested in the following composed maps:

$$\Phi^*\circ\Phi: M_d(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_d(\mathbb{C}) \quad\text{and}\quad \Phi_c^*\circ\Phi_c: M_d(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_d(\mathbb{C}),$$

which are again guaranteed to be completely positive (notice that these maps are neither trace-preserving nor unital in general). If people have looked at these kinds of compositions before, I would love to get hold of a reference.

In particular, I want to study the *supports* (or *ranges*) of the images of rank one projectors under the above maps. If the map $\Phi$ is also *completely copositive*, i.e. $\Phi\circ T$ is again a CPTP map and hence $T\circ \Phi^*$ is again unital and completely positive (where $T:M_d\rightarrow M_d$ is the *transpose* map), I claim that for all unit vectors $v\in\mathbb{C}^d$, the following inclusion holds
$$ \text{supp}\,\, [\Phi_c^* \circ \Phi_c](vv^*) \subseteq \text{supp}\,\, [\Phi^* \circ \Phi](vv^*).$$

Any help in proving/disproving the above claim would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[Cross posted on quantumcomputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16712/analyzing-the-composition-of-a-channel-with-its-adjoint-in-relation-with-an-iden)